# Webpack Code Splitting - How can I split into normal and vendor files?

Tags: webpack, .net-core

I'm trying to configure webpack in my ASP.NET Core project with code splitting.

I have the following files:

- main.ts (with dependency to jQuery)
- site.scss
- base.css

I want webpack to create a "dist" folder in my "wwwroot" folder with the following files:

- vendor.js (with jQuery / no source-map)
- site.js (with my code from main.ts and source-map)
- base.css
- site.css

My webpack configuration currently creates this output:

- base.css
- blubb.js (almost empty file)
- site.css (with source-map)
- site.js (with source-map)
- vendor.js (with source-map)

I know why webpack does these things but I don't know what I need to change.

Here is my **webpack.config.js** config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {

    const site = merge({
        entry: {
            site: ['./Client/ts/main.ts', './Client/scss/site.scss'],
            vendor: ['jquery']
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/')
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: "style-loader",
                        use: "css-loader"
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin("site.css"),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor' })
        ],

        devtool: "source-map"
    });

    const vendor = merge({
        entry: {
            site: ['./Client/css/base.css' ]
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/'),
            filename: 'blubb.js',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: "style-loader",
                        use: "css-loader"
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin("base.css")
        ]
    });

    return [site, vendor];
};
```

What can I change in my config to achieve my goal? I just want to separate my code from external dependencies.